Under what conditions can a function be applied inside and outside of an integral?
For what kinds of functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ does the following hold true?
$$f\left(\int g(x)dx\right)=\int f(g(x))dx$$
I am assuming Riemann integration but am open to hear how other formulations of the integral would alter the answer.
Additional context:
My students and I came across this differential equation:
$$y’+e^{2t}y=e^{3t}$$
After proceeding with the usual integration factor method, we arrived at needing to solve the following integral:
$$\int e^{\frac{1}{2}e^{2t}+3t}dt$$
We figured this would have some non-elementary solution, but the idea came up to try defining this integral to be the function $f(x)$ and then applying the natural log to both sides (with the hope of applying the natural log inside the integral). I said we might not be able to do this, but I became curious if there is ever a circumstance where this is possible.

You want this for $\int_a^b$ where $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary reals?  Perhaps $a \le b$?

@RobertIsrael either definite over the reals or indefinite over the reals is good

@geetha290krm Not quite: if $f(x) = ax + b$, $$f\left(\int g(x); dx\right) - \int f(g(x)); dx =  - b x +\text{constant}$$
$f(x) = a x$ would work.

Your main question is a bit too general to be answered in the affirmative for any but the obvious cases (i.e. the ones that use the linearity of the integral). For the particular integral you are looking at, indeed it has a non-elementary solution. Consider the substitution $u=-\frac12 e^{2t}$ and take a look at the incomplete Gamma function.

I set out to try to answer your question.  I found something that I hope that you'll like, although it is unexpected and not exactly what you are looking for.  But I thought that I would document it in case that you like it.  Here goes...
What if we can express, not function composition, but function multiplication:
$$g(x) \int{ h(x) } = \int{ g(x)\cdot h(x) } + \text{stuff} \tag{1}$$
Take the integral of $h(x)$
$$\int{h(x) dx} = \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \int{\Bigg( \underbrace{\frac{f'(x)}{g(x)}-\frac{f(x)g'(x)}{g(x)^2}}_{h(x)} \Bigg)dx} \tag{2}$$
Now take the integral of
$$\begin{align}
&\phantom{= } g(x)^2 \cdot \left(  \int{h(x) dx} \right) \\
&= g(x)^2 \cdot \left(  \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \right) \\
&= f(x)g(x) \\
&= \int{f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x) dx} \\
&= \int{  \frac{f'(x)}{g(x)} g(x)^2 + \frac{f(x)g'(x)}{g(x)^2} g(x)^2  dx} \\
&= \int{  \frac{f'(x)}{g(x)} g(x)^2 - \frac{f(x)g'(x)}{g(x)^2} g(x)^2 + 2\frac{f(x)g'(x)}{g(x)^2} g(x)^2  dx} \\
&=\int{  g(x)^2 \cdot \Bigg( \underbrace{\frac{f'(x)}{g(x)}-\frac{f(x)g'(x)}{g(x)^2}}_{h(x)} \Bigg)dx} + 2\int{ \frac{f(x)g'(x)}{g(x)^2} g(x)^2 dx} \\
&=\int{  g(x)^2 h(x)  dx} + 2\int{ \Bigg( \underbrace{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}}_{\int{h(x) dx}} \Bigg) \frac{g'(x)}{g(x)} dx} \\
&= \int{  g(x)^2 h(x)  dx} + 2 \int{  \Bigg(\underbrace{\int{h(x) dx}}_{j(x)}\Bigg)  \frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}  dx}  \tag{3}
\end{align}$$
Summarizing the calculations, we have:
$$g(x)^2 \cdot \left(  \int{h(x) dx} \right) = \left(\int{  g(x)^2 \cdot h(x)  dx}\right) + \underset{ \text{extra} }{   \left[  2 \int{  \Bigg(\underbrace{\int{h(x) dx}}_{j(x)}\Bigg)  \frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}  dx} \right]   } \tag{4}$$
I thought that the question is really interesting, and it's something I have thought about before.  Perhaps in the future we will have something closer to function composition of an integral!
